# How to attribute CSS file in .cshtml file in Visual Studio and using Azure Deployment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, razor

I'm trying to deploy a web app with Azure built in VS OSX and incorporate a CSS file into several .cshtml files. When I test the project on the local host the CSS loads appropriately, however when I publish to Azure I either get an error or the CSS file doesn't link up.

I have tried the several methods of inclusion below, and other like combinations, to no avail:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href='@Url.Content("./css/login_styles.css")'/>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="~/css/login_styles.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" 
href="~/css/login_styles.css"/>
```

Sometimes I get an error from Azure when loading the particular .cshtml with a random reference number I can't make sense of. I'm also having a hard time figuring which CSS reference is correlated to an error (due to caching possibly?)

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyxkA.png)

[Here is my file structure for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grRrq.png)

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: Make sure that your file is included in your project...you can right click the file and select the `Include in Project` menu item....

Comment: Might that be a windows feature? I'm on visual studio for mac